# Linking to page with loaded iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I'm working on a site with multiple pages - the master page contains different pages which it loads one at a time (depending on what one clicked) into an`<iframe>`. It works nicely on any platform now. But now I can't share a link to a specific page ! I can only share the home page!

How can I share a link to a page that will reflect the fact I'm not in fact directing to the home page but to the page with the iframe that loaded another page?

Comment: Check out the HTML5 History API (`pushState` and `popState`) - I'd also perform the loading without iframes - those are frowned upon and your source will surely be checked in a portfolio site.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Checking History API. You have seen the portfolio (it was linked in my post) can you suggest an alternative to iFrames?